How to edit bar 5 to 8 on an 8-bar clip on Roland MC-101?
The Roland MC-101 has LED indicators for the first 4 bars to select which bar to edit, but a clip can be up to eight bars in length. How do I edit bars 5 to 8?

May you more clearly express what do you want? What exactly do you (which buttons you press, step by step) when you select one of the first 4 bars to edit it? (Not in a comment, but adding it directly to your question.)
